# Formating Currency with Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, currency, nsnumberformatter

I am trying to format an integer to a currency with this code:

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
NSString *str = [formatter stringFromNumber:num];
```

Everything works fine but the currency is coming from the locale of the iOS.
Is there any way to change it using "**EUR**" or "**USD**" as currency?

PS. I tried also `currencySymbol` and `currencyCode` which change the string but not the formatting!

**Update:**
I am asking if there is any way to format it with EUR USD and not de-DE or en-US

Comment: So change `de-DE` to `EUR` then in Adams example

Comment: ` formatter.locale = [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"EUR"];` won't work!

Comment: The point is format it to whatever currency you want! people are giving their time to help you for free so drop the attitude.  If you search SO there are many answers on this

Comment: I apologize if my answers made you think that I demand the answers from other users instead for asking for help. Maybe is because my English are not good but nobody seems to understand my question. I am closing the question

Comment: Ok no problem close and restate it then if you need to

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is to set the locale to your formatter. For example:

```
formatter.locale = [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"de-DE"];
```

Comment: I am asking if there is any way to format it with EUR USD and not de-DE or en-US

Comment: You said that you have tried `currencyCode`. If you don't want to change the whole locale, changing only the code should be enough, or am I missing something from your question?

Comment: I want to change local using EUR or USD. Is there any way or I should maintain a plist with USD mapped to en_US and so on?